# Lua convert string to number - locale dependent

Tags: lua, locale

Just noticed that *tostring()* and *tonumber()* in Lua is locale dependent. Any idea of how to convert a string to a number without using *tonumber()*? Thanks.

e.g. convert string "-58.5" to -58.5

Also when I tried to pass a number with dot to a function, the function converts "." to "," automatically. How do you usually solve this kind of problems?

> function test(num)
>        print(num)
>   end
>
> test(-58.5) -- it prints -58,5

Comment: Without tonumber? You could try adding 0 to the string. It should do automatic conversion for you. Probably still locale dependant.

Answer (score 4):

The result of your `test` function is itself locale-dependent. (On my machine with default settings I get a result of `-58.5` since my locale is `en_US.UTF-8`.)

You should be able to set the locale however you like via [`os.setlocale`](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.setlocale). That might be simpler than writing your own `tonumber` function.

For example:

```
local function nshow(n) print(n) end
local n = -58.5

print(os.setlocale("de_DE.UTF-8"))
nshow(n)
print(os.setlocale("C"))
nshow(n)
```

Output:

```
de_DE.UTF-8
-58,5
C
-58.5
```

Comment: Thanks. The control system where the code is running doesn't allow os.setlocale(). Anyway, I used a workaround to get the decimal separator and then replace "." of the tonumber() input with the decimal separator.

Comment: And apparently Lua does not handle thousands separators correctly in `tonumber` either.