# Locale dependent string to number conversion

Tags: lua, type-conversion

I want to convert localized strings to numbers; including the decimal separator and/or thousands separator. It works for strings where there is only a "." as decimal separator, but won't work, i.e. returns `nil`, for the following cases:

1. "21,1" (expected: 21.1)
2. "1,231.0" (expected: 1231.0)
3. "1.000.101,044" (expected: 1000101.044)

The problem is that I won't know which locale is set beforehand so the conversion must be generic.

Is there a locale-dependent string to number conversion?

Comment: How do you understand whether `tonumber(1.001)` should be `1001` or `1001/1000`?  The dot might be thousands separator or a decimal point depending on the locale.

Answer (score 0):

Sort of – there is no specific conversion function that would accept a locale, but it can be set for the whole process with [`os.setlocale`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#pdf-os.setlocale):

```lua
assert(os.setlocale("de.utf8"))
print(tonumber("1,2"))
```

This sets the C locale to German (UTF-8), assuming it is installed on the system, which will affect all conversions, but also things like formatting, collation, time etc. You have to use `os.setlocale(name, "numeric")` to affect only number formatting and parsing rules.

You can do this multiple times, until the conversion succeeds.

Comment: I've read that in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35003914/lua-convert-string-to-number-locale-dependent and tried it, but maybe it was just an interpreter error on https://www.lua.org/cgi-bin/demo.

Comment: Unfortunately this only works partially, i.e. `print(tonumber("1.111,2"))` returns `nil`. I guess I will have to work with some workarounds to reformat whatever input I'm getting and enforce one locale.

Comment: Ah it depends on the locales installed on the system, there is no guarantee that the demo will have it (and seems like I was incorrect in the name anyway, at least in the case of Unix). It's not platform-independent.